# http post request is not working in android

Tags: php, android

I sent a httpPost request in android to php page (In php page I used a php code to insert data into the table.) In android app is working fine but there are no activity in php page.

Here is the full code

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` does not work on the emulators. To access localhost use `10.0.2.2` in place of `127.0.0.1`.

When using an android device, connect your computer and device to same network and use the computer's ip address to access your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use your ip address in the HttpPost

```
 httppost= new HttpPost("http://ipaddress/android_connect/create_product.php");
```

I think this will help you

Comment: php page is running on this link http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php any problem of this ?

Comment: see this tutorial


  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Use your ip address as shivam verma said don't use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes I used                                                          httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/android_connect/create_product.php");